# Is it possible to check for an unsigned byte in a python byte array?

Tags: python, byte

I have a byte array that should contain bytes, ints, etc and one unsigned byte:

The unsigned byte is created in the following way:

```py
unsigned_int = int.to_bytes(1, "little", signed=False)

byteslist.append(unsigned_int)
```

The signed bytes is created as follows:

```py
signed_byte = signed.to_bytes(1, "little", signed=True)
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to loop through the bytelist and find out where the unsigned byte is? Is there a way to differentiate between the two?

I've tried to find out how I can differentiate between signed and unsigned ints and convert bytes to ints and python but I got nothing;

> "You cannot do that. Signed and unsigned are just different
> interpretations of the same bit pattern"

Comment: Well you have already found the answer: *You cannot do that. Signed and unsigned are just different interpretations of the same bit pattern*. And that is true, a byte string is an array of 8 bits byte. There is not problems for bytes 0 to 127, but for example unsigned byte 255 and signed byte -1 have the exact same representation 0xFF in hexa. And there is no mean to guess whether that 0xFF is intended to be a 255 or a -1.

Comment: `signed_byte = signed.to_bytes(1, "little", signed=True)` doesn't mean you "made signed bytes". It means you made a bytestring containing bytes that, when interpreted as a little-endian 2's complement representation of an integer, represent the integer you named `signed`.

Comment: If you need to know the position of the unsigned byte - store it into another array.

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. The specification of the protocol will tell you which byte should be interpreted as unsigned. You don't look for it, you just access that byte by its index and parse it as unsigned. I suggest you look at the `struct` library.

Answer (score 1):

No, bytes are not signed.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

```
int.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder='big', *, signed=False)
```

The signed argument determines whether two’s complement is used to represent the integer. If signed is False and a negative integer is given, an OverflowError is raised. The default value for signed is False.

So this is not about signed byte, but interpretation of the integer argument.